# How does Django decrypt EncryptedCharField fields?

Tags: django, encryption

So I've got a field in my Postgres database that is a `bytea` type. I know the decrypted value and also the key, but can't figure out how to get from that raw database value to the decrypted string. I believe I'm looking for the algorithm that Django uses to decrypt these values and how I can use that to encrypt another string. Django supposedly uses the package Keyczar, which mentions using `Crypter` package to encrypt/decrypt things. I'm unable to install that package so I'm not sure how to go about this in another way.

I ultimately want to update a value in the EncryptedCharField field in my database since it is not valid anymore - is there a way to get this encrypted value online or within Python?

Adding relevant code. There's a lot of parameters and objects being passed around, so hopefully it doesn't make it hard to follow the code below:

```
# How the field is getting read from Postgres: 
server_password = EncryptedCharField(null=True, max_length=255)

# Get some other settings info from another table:
settings = SourceSystemSettings.objects.get(school=school, source_system=SourceSystem.objects.VENDOR)

# Setting up the pysftp connection object:
SourceFTP(hosts=[settings.server_host, SERVER_INTERNAL],
               user=settings.server_user,
               password=settings.server_password,
               directory=settings.server_dir)

# Connecting using the password and other settings:
connection = pysftp.Connection(host, username=user, password=password, cnopts=cnopts)
```

Comment: Do you have the code for the app? Without knowing the algorithm/package used to encrypt the field you would be limited to guess work

Comment: Yeah, I could share code, but I'm not sure if it would really help, as there's nothing being done on the database field. I'll add in what I think is relevant to the original post

Comment: You have a Django app that is successfully encrypting and decrypting the field? Can you share the package that `EncryptedCharField` is being imported from and the python version?

Comment: Ah I didn't realize it was getting imported from a separate library. Looks like I'm using `django-fernet-fields==0.5`

Comment: You can see how the internals of the field work on github https://github.com/orcasgit/django-fernet-fields/blob/master/fernet_fields/fields.py